# Distinct records with geo_distance sort on aggregation ES

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm working on nearby API using elasticsearch.

I'm trying to run 4 actions in ES query

- match condition (here running a script to get records within radius)
- get distinct records based on company's Key (want to get one record from a company)
- sort records based on geo_distance
- add the field as **Distance** to get the distance between user and location

Here is my code:

```
const query = {
  query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          customQuery,
          {
            term: {
              "schedule.isShopOpen": true,
            },
          },
          {
            term: {
              isBranchAvailable: true,
            },
          },
          {
            term: {
              branchStatus: "active",
            },
          },
          {
            match:{
              shopStatus: "active"
            }
          },
          {
            script: {
              script: {
                params: {
                  lat: parseFloat(req.lat),
                  lon: parseFloat(req.lon),
                },
                source:
                  "doc['location'].arcDistance(params.lat, params.lon) / 1000 <= doc['searchRadius'].value",
                lang: "painless",
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
  },
  aggs: {
    duplicateCount: {
      terms: {
        field: "companyKey",
        size: 10000,
      },
      aggs: {
        duplicateDocuments: {
          top_hits: {
            sort: [
              {
                _geo_distance: {
                  location: {
                    lat: parseFloat(req.lat),
                    lon: parseFloat(req.lon),
                  },
                  order: "asc",
                  unit: "km",
                  mode: "min",
                  distance_type: "arc",
                  ignore_unmapped: true,
                },
              },
            ],
            script_fields: {
              distance: {
                script: {
                  params: {
                    lat: parseFloat(req.lat),
                    lon: parseFloat(req.lon),
                  },
                  inline: `doc['location'].arcDistance(params.lat, params.lon)/1000`,
                },
              },
            },

            stored_fields: ["_source"],
            size: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Here's the out put:

```
data: [
  {
    companyKey: "1234",
    companyName: "Floward",
    branchKey: "3425234",
    branch: "Mursilat",
    distance: 1.810064121687324,
  },
  {
    companyKey: "0978",
    companyName: "Dkhoon",
    branchKey: "352345",
    branch: "Wahah blue branch ",
    distance: 0.08931851500047634,
  },
  {
    companyKey: "567675",
    companyName: "Abdulaziz test",
    branchKey: "53425",
    branch: "Jj",
    distance: 0.011447273197846672,
  },
  {
    companyKey: "56756",
    companyName: "Mouj",
    branchKey: "345345",
    branch: "King fahad",
    distance: 5.822936713752124,
  },
];
```

I have two issues

- How to sort records based on geo_distance
- will query actions(match, script) apply to aggregation data...?

Can you please help me out to solve these issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more appropriate query for your use case

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "200km",
            "distance_type": "arc",
            "location": {
              "lat": 40,
              "lon": -70
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "shopStatus": "active"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "companyKey"
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 40,
          "lon": 71
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km",
        "mode": "min",
        "distance_type": "arc",
        "ignore_unmapped": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": ["*"], 
  "script_fields": {
    "distance_in_m": {
      "script": "doc['location'].arcDistance(40, -70)" // convert to unit required
    }
  }
}
```

1. **Filter** instead of **must** - since you are just filtering documents, filter will be faster as it does not score documents unlike must
2. [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html)

> You can use the collapse parameter to collapse search results based on field values. The collapsing is done by selecting only the top sorted document per collapse key.

3. [Geo distance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) instead of script -- to find documents with in distance
4. script field to get distance